# Printing the alphabet on one line python

Tags: python, alphabet, chr

How can I print the alphabet on one line using chr(), with each letter seperated by a space.

My current code:

```
for x in range(97,123):
    letter = chr(x)
    alphabet = "" + letter
    print alphabet
```

Comment: Also: ``import string;print(string.lowercase)``. ;-)

Comment: We have to use `chr`, so the solution is: `import string; print ' '.join(chr(ord(c)) for c in string.ascii_lowercase)`

Comment: @Matthias: I _assume_ that's intended to be humorous. :)

Comment: @PM 2Ring: Well the standard way to do it (with Python 3) would be `import functools; import operator; import string; print(functools.reduce(operator.add, map(lambda x: x+' ', string.ascii_lowercase)))`, but a solution with `chr` was required. ;-)

Comment: @Matthias Nice. And some people say Germans don't have a sense of humour...

Comment: @PM 2Ring: I work in IT. I'm supposed to be ... different.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a list comprehension (like in Matt's answer) or do you have to use a `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `,` after `print` statement so that

```
print alphabet,
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import string
print " ".join(string.lowercase)
```

Or if the use of `chr` is mandatory, as mentioned in the comments:

```
print " ".join([chr(c) for c in xrange(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1)])
```

Comment: I must admit your 1st solution is cool - I don't think I've ever noticed `.join()` being used with a string argument before, but of course it makes perfect sense, since strings are iterable.